# WinForms WebBrowser control — Get Document Elements After AJAX?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax, webbrowser-control

I'm using WebControl from Windows Forms in C# and I'm trying to load a Web Ajax content (i suposed that the content is ajax) this is the code of the page retrieve from the explorer:

```
<ul id="building">
   <li id="button1" class="on">
    <div class="supply1">
     <div class="buildingimg">
      <a class="fastBuild tips" title="|Expandir Mina de metal al nivel 11" href="index.php?page=resources&session=ccec6b62991a&modus=1&type=1&menge=1&token=ae485059d2eb1d87bc6f181744a4b4ab">
       <img src="img/layout/sofort_bauen.gif" width="22" height="14" />
      </a><a class="detail_button tips slideIn" title="|Mina de metal" ref="1" id="details"
       href="#"><span class="ecke"><span class="level"><span class="textlabel">Mina de metal
       </span>10 </span></span></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
```

When press the image a new panel load without reload entire page.

How i can simulate the click on image to load the panel?

In other control in this page i use myWebBrowser.Document.RaiseEvent("") Method to simulate clicks, but in this case no is any onclick event ... i don't understand how launch the loading of the panel ..

In the bottom of the page are some javascript methods (i not put all scripts because are big)

PD: Sorry my English, i'm studying it. thanks.

I'm re-reading the code and i view this code:

```
function loadDetails(type)
{
    $.post(
        "index.php?page=resources&session=ccec6b62991a&ajax=1",
        { type: type},
        function(data){
            $("#detail").html(data);
            $("#techDetailLoading").hide();
            $("input[type='text']:first", document.forms["form"]).focus();

            reloadCluetip();
        }
    );
}
```

Can it relationship with my question?

Comment: BTW, the C# programming language does not have a webbrowser control. The .NET Framework does.

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.webbrowser_ctl/browse_thread/thread/e5eeb4a9111b16af/97c0fd20b3deb26?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=idispatchex+showmodaldialog#097c0fd20b3deb26
It is for overriding the showModalDialog function, you can override custom function too.

Answer (score 0):

Mythox,
I tried to do the same on the same page, actually at the moment the dialog box opens perfectly and on 4 cases over 10 I'm also able to start the construction required in the new dialog opening.
The problem is that my method is not fail safe 100% but for sure it is one way to arrive at the solution.
I post the code here.

```
     HtmlDocument doc = Program.BrowsingSystem.Document;
            HtmlElement ele = doc.GetElementById("button3");
            if (!ConstructionButtonIsAllowedToBePressed(ele))
                return new ActionResponse(false);
            if (ele.GetAttribute("classname").ToLower().Contains("disabled")) //the unit is disabled due to missing resources or other activities running
            {
                return new ActionResponse(false);
            }
            if (ele.GetAttribute("classname").ToLower().Contains("off")) //the unit is unreacheble at this planet level
            {
                return new ActionResponse(false);
            }

            ele = ele.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.NextSibling;

            object obj = ele.DomElement;
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("click");
            mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);


            semaphoreForDocCompletedEvent = WaitForDocumentCompleted(genWaitingTimeForNonEventingActions*2);

            ele = doc.GetElementById("planet");

            ele = ele.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling;

            obj = ele.DomElement;
            mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("submit");
            mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);

            semaphoreForDocCompletedEvent = WaitForDocumentCompleted(genWaitingTimeForNonEventingActions);
            if (!semaphoreForDocCompletedEvent)
                return new ActionResponse(false);
```